# Problem with loading TFS reports

Tags: tfs, reportserver, tfs-reports

I have installed TFS on a single server and configured it completely as mentioned in the documentations and created a Project using MSF for agile process. Now when I'm trying to browse to the reports of the project site (http://tfs/Sites/MyProject) I get the following error:

**The path of the item '/MyProject/Bug Rates' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath)**

Can anyone tell me how can I solve this? 
Thanks

**EDIT:**

I have changed the report server database connection mode to Native and now I get the following error:

**The item '/MyProject/Bug Rates' cannot be found. (rsItemNotFound)**

I also tried repairing the TFS, but it didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: No offense, but when I first read this question I thought it was dangerously close to "TPS report cover sheets" from 'Office Space': http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0151804/quotes

Answer (score 0):

Do you run TFS 2008 or 2010?

In TFS 2010 you configure it without SSRS. If it is not configured, then when you create a new team project the reports are not installed of course.

Answer (score 0):

I also run into this problem today and this is how I fixed it.

1. Open your Web.config and locate `"ReportServerPath"`. It looks like
   this:

   < add key="ReportServerPath" value="/< YourReportpath >.Reports/"/>
2. Now right click on Reports and select `'Properties'`. Locate `'TargetReportFolder'`

The `'ReportServerPath'` of your Web.config `should be the same` with your `'TargetReportFolder'` of your Reports Properties.